# Proxy HTTPS requests internally to the internet

Tags: proxy, cron, healthcheck

Due to security reasons, one of our hosts **HOST-B** doesn't have a connection to the internet. But I need to set up HTTPS traffic to healthchecks.io to monitor cron jobs. All incoming traffic is proxied with HAproxy through **HOST-A**.

How is it possible to proxy the HTTPS requests to https://hc-ping.com via **HOST-A** to healthchecks.io?

*Side note: I didn't set up the HAproxy proxying so it's new to me.*

Comment: Can HOST-B send emails? If so, you could send emails to your-uuid@hc-ping.com addresses for the same effect.

Comment: Hi @PēterisCaune. No, the host doesn't have any input and output from and to the internet allowed. So it must be proxied through HOST-A

Comment: I'm assuming HOST-B is in a restricted environment because of regulations or security requirements. The same regulations and requirements will likely also dictate what technical solution is acceptable for "punching out" a hole to an external monitoring service. I would consult with whoever set up firewall on HOST-B and haproxy on HOST-A.

Note that requests to hc-ping.com could in theory be used to exfiltrate data (arbitrary data can go in HTTP POST request body).

Answer (score 0):

Not without configuring this specifically on HA-Proxy and even then a true forward proxy like Squid might be a better option.